# Will my other partitions be wiped when doing a clean install of Mavericks?

Tags: macbook-pro, macos

**Situation**

I have two partitions: Mac OS X, and Windows Bootcamp. Will the Windows partition get caught in the wiping process when attempting a Mavericks clean install? I think people call it spring cleaning. The clean install is due to the program clutter I have (python, mysql, apache2, etc).

I'm using a Macbook Pro (Early 2011).

Comment: You might want to explain what you mean by wiping. Are you going to format the entire disk?

Answer (score 1):

> The windows partition wont be touched if your just re-installing on
>   the Mac partition. unless you format the entire disk then you have a
>   problem

***"More in depth explanation

Partition Map or Table  - is instructions written at the beginning of the drive that tell the hardware it's running from: what, how many, and where the partitions are on the drive. There is only one partition map on the drive. It can be MBR or GUID.

Partition  - is a space on the drive that appears as another volume, but still resides on the same piece of physical hardware.

Formatting - is how a entire drive or partition is structured to hold data, one drive can be partitioned into many separate partitions each with their own formatting. The Partition Map holds all the information of what is what.

Changing the partition map/table scheme will erase all data on the entire drive, it's like burning a treasure map, no directions anymore.

Changing the format of a single partition on a multi-partitioned drive only erases the data on the partition being formatted."***

SOURCE : https://discussions.apple.com/docs/DOC-3044