# Can I clean install Mavericks preserving other bootable partitions (Ubuntu on ext4)?

Tags: macos, partition, install, unix

I have checked [Will my other partitions be wiped when doing a clean install of Mavericks?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/126979) but I'd like to make sure whether a clean install of Mavericks to my specific OS X partition won't mess up with the rest of the disk. OS X generally doesn't recognize other partitions types beyond the Windows types.

Is such clean install prone to error even if I take care of asking installation to not touch the partition scheme?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you clear you partition using Disk Utility and then boot into Internet Recovery or install from another location (for example a USB flash drive) you should be fine, OS X will only be installed (and only effect) the partition you choose to install it on at the start of the installation process.

Comment: does that means I have to first clear the partition before the clean install? or is it safe to just overwrite current installation if there's such option.

Comment: It's how I choose to do it. You can just launch into the boot disk and it will overwrite it for you.

Comment: thanks, I have already erased it first from disk utility in the Mavericks thumb drive

Comment: ok, I was using [rEFInd](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/getting.html) already, it was a matter of reinstalling it after the clean install, no problems =D

Comment: @pepper_chico Good!